# How to get data from bluetooth 4 heart rate sensor from windows?

Tags: node.js, windows-8.1, bluetooth-lowenergy, sensors

I have a Mio Link heart rate monitor, which has ANT+ and Bluetooth Smart capabilities. I have a Windows 8.1 laptop, which has Bluetooth Smart Ready capability. Is there a way to access the sensor data from the laptop using node.js?